# How to declare ToolbarItem button without using XAML?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm making my first app and don't want to use XAML yet.

I need to make button as `ToolbarItem` object, but can't declare it:

```
ToolbarItem AddButton = new ToolbarItem("AddButton", "AddIcon.png", /*action*/);
```

What is `Action` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/constructor/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem.ToolbarItem/p/System.String/System.String/System.Action/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItemOrder/System.Int32/). Its the function name which will be called when the item is activated. 
Activated   Raised when the ToolbarItem is touched or clicked.

That is, this will be the name of your eventhalndler function that handles touches or clicks on that item.